# multiple join on conditions sql to linq

Tags: c#, linq

how can i change the sql below to a linq.

```
select distinct * from dbo.TbleA a
left outer join dbo.TbleB b on a.schid = b.schid
left outer join dbo.TbleC c on b.addrid=c.addrid
and c.userid=a.userid
where b.addrid=1
```

here is my linq version which is causing error:

```
from a in db.TbleA
join b in db.TbleB on a.schid equals b.schid
join c in db.TbleC on new { w = b.addrid, z = a.userid } equals new { w=(int?)c.addrid, z=c.userid}
where (b.addrid == 1)
```

i am getting error around here:

> join c in db.TbleC on new { w = b.addrid, z = a.userid } equals new {
>   w=(int?)c.addrid, z=c.userid}

i do understand where the problem is i am comparing to two tables in my join.
thanks and the error is:

> "the type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect""Type inference failed in the call to join"

```
b.addrid - int, 
a.userid - string, 
c.addrid - int?
c.userid - string
```

Comment: Please say exactly what the error is - it's very hard to help when we can't see the problem.

Comment: Your sql query is not clear : if you `left join` on `TbleB` and use a `Where` clause on `tbleB`, it's just as if you're doing an inner join. Do you want a left or an inner join ? By the way, why do you have to cast to an `int?` b.addrid and c.addrid are not of the same type ?

Comment: @JonSkeet it said the type of join is incorrect, i think i also mention where the error is. i do understand where the problem is if you look carefully at my linq. see my updates.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus i cast to accept nulls which is correct in linq. also what is an inner join in linq then?

Comment: I don't say it's incorrect. You just need to be sure that "w" and "z" (in your anonymous types) are of the same type in both part of the join (so if c.addrid is a nullable int, b.addrid must also be a nullable int)

Comment: I suspect it said more than just "the type of join is incorrect". You say which line the error is in, but you haven't given the full error message. Copy and paste the *exact* compiler message into your question. *Always* do this when you ask a question that's about a compilation error - just like you should *always* include full exception details when asking a question about an exception.

Comment: @JonSkeet "the type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect", that is the error, there is no other error. thanks.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus actually other than the error, int? is correct way to use as it is shown in this examples here: http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/linq/UXPF181012-SQL-Joins-with-C

Comment: I suspect the *full* error message also includes "Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'." Anyway, at least that's a start. Right, now what are the types of `b.addrid`, `a.userid`, `c.addrid` and `c.userid`? (If you could show us a [mcve] I suspect we could clear this up in minutes...)

Comment: @JonSkeet yes indeed, "Type inference failed in the call to join"

Comment: Right, so in future, the right thing to do would be to include the *full* error message in the question. I suggest you edit that in, along with the other information I've asked about...

Comment: @JonSkeet made updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't really tell what's wrong with your current query in terms of compilation without knowing the types involved, but it wouldn't be equivalent to your original SQL anyway, as you want left outer joins. I suspect you want something more like:

```
from a in db.TbleA
join b in db.TbleB on a.schid equals b.schid into bs
from b in bs.DefaultIfEmpty()
join c in db.TbleC on new { w = (int?)b?.addrid, z = a.userid }
               equals new { w = c.addrid, z = c.userid } into cs
from c in cs.DefaultIfEmpty()
where (b.addrid == 1)
```

That's if you can use C# 6 with the null conditional operator, of course. If not, you would at least *logically* need:

```
from a in db.TbleA
join b in db.TbleB on a.schid equals b.schid into bs
from b in bs.DefaultIfEmpty()
join c in db.TbleC on new { w = (b == null ? default(int?) : (int?)b.addrid), z = a.userid }
               equals new { w = c.addrid, z = c.userid } into cs
from c in cs.DefaultIfEmpty()
where b == null || b.addrid == 1
```

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: Good catch - added.

Comment: @JonSkeet i am getting this error for "The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."

Comment: @Menew: Unfortunately it's hard to diagnose exactly what the problem is remotely. I suggest you try to reduce this to an absolutely minimal query demonstrating the problem, then ask a new question - although I suspect that in the process of reducing it to a minimal query, you'll be able to work out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your error is caused by trying to compare anonymous classes within a LinQ statement which are not of the same type. I suggest you change the join to the following:

```
from a in db.TbleA
join b in db.TbleB on a.schid equals b.schid
join c in db.TbleC on new { w = (int?)b.addrid, z = a.userid } equals new { w=(int?)c.addrid, z=c.userid}
where (b.addrid == 1)
```

Comment: Using anonymous types in a join is absolutely fine.

Comment: My bad. Was a little too quick there.
I only use it for `let` and `select` and couldn't image that they can be used for equals.

Comment: This still isn't equivalent to the original query though.

Comment: this worked and removed the errors, so i added int? to both the comparison

Comment: I suggest you look at the SQL that's being generated though - I strongly suspect it won't be what you want, given that it's not a left outer join.

Comment: @JonSkeet you are right. I totally ignored the SQL he had. Yours is the correct solution.